# Mysqli fetch_assoc vs fetch_array

Tags: php, mysqli

When I'm returning one row from a table, to gather the results I usually use e.g.:

```
$info = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

What is the difference between that and:

```
$info = $result->fetch_array();
```

Is there a reason to use one over the other when returning only one row, or is it just personal preference?

Comment: They both return an associative array, my question is: why use one over the other? The manual does not answer that question as far as I can see.

Comment: take a look at here http://www.spearheadsoftwares.com/tutorials/php-performance-benchmarking/50-mysql-fetch-assoc-vs-mysql-fetch-array-vs-mysql-fetch-object

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**It's all about performance**

`fetch_array()` returns one array with both numeric keys, and associative strings *(column names)*, so here you can either use `$row['column_name']` or `$row[0]`

Where as `fetch_assoc()` will return string indexed key array and no numeric array so you won't have an option here of using numeric keys like <s>`$row[0]`</s>.

So the latter one is better in performance compared to `fetch_array()` and obviously using named indexes is far better compared to numeric indexes.

Comment: actually, when returning a single row, I wasn't able to use fetch array with the column name. I had to switch to fetch assoc and it istantly worked...

Comment: _obviously using named indexes is far better compared to numeric indexes_ : this is a personal opinion, not a fact. Usually this is true, however there are situations where it's easier to handle numbered columns. For example if the SQL command is generated automaitcally.

Answer (score 12):

fetch_array returns value with indexing.
But Fetch_assoc just returns the the value.

for example 
fetch_array returns

```
[0] => 11
[id] => 11
[1] => 2014-12-29
[date] => 2014-12-29
```

here array location 0 contains 11 also this location name is 'id'.

same things fetch_assoc will returns

```
[id] => 11
[date] => 2014-12-29
```

means just returns the value.

Answer (score 3):

(PHP 5)
From: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

> mysqli_result::fetch_array -- mysqli_fetch_array — Fetch a result row
>   as an associative, a numeric array, or both

So effectively, `fetch_array()` and `fetch_assoc()` can be essentially equivalent calls.  As for performance, I recommend using whichever call that results in more readable code and only be concerned about the performance after you've clearly identified the call as a performance issue.  It's more likely that you've got more serious performance issues where you least expect them to be.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch_array` will give you key/value pairs and with indexes, where as `fetch_assoc` will give you only the key/value pairs but not with indexes. For example:

```
//fetch_array output be like:
[name]=>'someName'
[0]=>'someName'
[email]=>'some@some.com'
[1]=>'some@some.com'

//fetch_assoc output be like

[name]=>'someName'
[email]=>'some@some.com'
```