# singly mysql field in an associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

I currently have this code:

```
$res= $mysqli->query("SELECT titre FROM Bibliographie WHERE Nom_Auteur LIKE '%$auteur%'"); 

while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

The outcome is:

```
array(1) {
    ["titre"]=>
    string(65) "Le droit privé dans les Pays-Bas méridionaux du 12e au 18e siècle"
}
 array(1) {
    ["titre"]=>
    string(41) "Le droit foncier à Bruxelles au moyen-âge"  
} 
array(1) {
    ["titre"]=>
    string(78) "Les sûretés personnelles dans les Pays-Bas méridionaux du XIe au XVIIIe siècle"
}
array(1) {
    ["titre"]=>
    string(44) "Chartes du chapitre de St-Gudule à Bruxelles"
}
```

But I want the outcome to be:

```
[0] => "Le droit privé dans les Pays-Bas méridionaux du 12e au 18e siècle"
[1] => "Le droit foncier à Bruxelles au moyen-âge"
[2] => "Chartes du chapitre de St-Gudule à Bruxelles"
```

I can't get my head around this and need some help obtaining this simple outcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various options to do this,

1) You can use **`fetch_all()`** method instead of `fetch_assoc()` to get all data in one variable at once and then you can flattern the array using this function.

```
$res= $mysqli->query("SELECT titre FROM Bibliographie WHERE Nom_Auteur LIKE '%$auteur%'"); 
$result = array_map(function($ary) {return $ary['titre'];}, $res->fetch_all());
// Just two lines of code. No big deal
```

2) As Gerald Schneider suggested,

```
$res= $mysqli->query("SELECT titre FROM Bibliographie WHERE Nom_Auteur LIKE '%$auteur%'"); 

$result = array();
while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc()) {
     $result[] = $row['titre'];
} 
var_dump($result);
// simple and easy to understand
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your desired result this way:

```
$result = array();
while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $result[] = $row['titre'];
} 
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `while ($row=$res->fetch_array()){var_dump($row);}` instead. See [Mysqli fetch_assoc vs fetch_array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361184/mysqli-fetch-assoc-vs-fetch-array)