# PHP/MYSQLI: fetch_assoc() vs fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there any difference of any kind between `$result->fetch_assoc()` and
`$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` or they are exactly the same thing?

I have searched a bit before making this question but the only thing I've found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361184/mysqli-fetch-assoc-vs-fetch-array)) is that `$result->fetch_array()` with no params allows numeric and associative indexes while
`$result->fetch_assoc()` only allows the associative indexes and therefore the last one has a better performance.

Comment: They're the same, if you have the `MYSQLI_ASSOC` argument to the `fetch_array()` function. If you don't have that particular argument, they're different.

Comment: If you use the `MYSQLI_ASSOC` constant with `fetch_array` it is _exactly the same_ as `fetch_assoc`. They both call the same internal function. They are essentially aliases. I would expect to see negligible if any difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, purpose and returned formats.

`fetch_array()` has more output formats. You can see here [PHP Manual : mysqli_result::fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Whereas [PHP Manual : mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) outputs a single format.

Comment: Why do you thing `fetch_array()` is slower?

Comment: You know, i have nothing to back that up. My logic is that is most likely a larger code block with more logic to process. However, probably aliases, as mentioned by @DontPanic. So, i'll strike it from the answer. In essence, PHP could depreciate `fetch_assoc` and `fetch_row` in favor of `fetch_array` to consolidate the code.

Comment: Well, I guess `fetch_array()` takes more time than `fetch_assoc()` or `fetch_row()` to produce the array it returns (if we consider the case when `$resulttype` is `MYSQLI_BOTH`, it puts each value twice in the generated array). While in absolute numbers, `fetch_array()` is indeed slower, all three functions probably need 1/1000 of the time needed by the query to execute. Choosing between `fetch_array()` and `fetch_assoc()` is not a source of performance improvement.

Comment: @axiac agreed :)

Comment: Buddy, you will get more upvotes if your answers are more complete, adding links is not enough, include more explanations in case the links stop working, and add examples with its resulting data.

Answer (score 0):

fetch_array() is used when you need access to both associative and numeric indexes.

Use fetch_assoc() when you only need associative indexes.

Php.net docs say

> Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both

[Php.net fetch_array() description](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation of [`mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) and [`mysqli_result::fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)?

The last one explains the possible values for its argument:

> **$resulttype**
>
> This optional parameter is a constant indicating what type of array should be produced from the current row data. The possible values for this parameter are the constants `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, `MYSQLI_NUM`, or `MYSQLI_BOTH`.
>
> By using the `MYSQLI_ASSOC` constant this function will behave identically to the [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), while `MYSQLI_NUM` will behave identically to the [`mysqli_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) function. The final option `MYSQLI_BOTH` will create a single array with the attributes of both.