# Is there any need to use fetch_object or fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysqli

I recently found out that I can print results from database without using `mysqli_fetch_object` function.

So for example:
Let's say we have simple sql select statment which would be executed by using something like this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'example_db');
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users");
```

Next step would be something like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) echo $row->username
```

Where username is corresponding column name in table of users.

Then I figured out this works too for printing it out:

```
foreach($result as $row) echo $row['username'];
```

After couple of `var_dumps` and fruther reading of php documentation. My only guess would be that this is possible because of this:

> 5.4.0 Iterator support was added, as mysqli_result now implements Traversable.

So if my claims are true. Is there any need for using something like 
`mysqli_fetch_object` or similar function `mysqli_fetch_array` ?

Comment: *"So if my claims are true. Is there any need for using something like mysqli_fetch_object or similar function mysqli_fetch_array ?"*  - Consult the manuals; all have a specific reason.

Comment: `foreach($resault as $row) echo $row['username'];` - That `$resault` is a typo, right?

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing out. I edited it.

Comment: If you loop over the `mysqli_result` object, you're limited to array-formatted results, whereas `mysqli_fetch_object` will provide them as objects. If you're happy with that, then like you say, you can just iterate over it directly. It's very much just a matter of taste, though.

Comment: in addition to @iainn : if you do some further formatting or anything else then it's better to use objects as they are passed by reference as default, array is not

Comment: It's dependent on your requirements, what data types your script needs and what your programming preference is, if you need an object use `mysqli_fetch_object`! There is also a performance element associated with each method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361184/mysqli-fetch-assoc-vs-fetch-array

Comment: The question IMHO is too broad and probably opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically 3 ways to get the results in PHP via MySQLi API.

In order of preference:

1. Fetch all records into a PHP array. You can use the `fetch_all()` method to get all records into a multidimensional array. You can decide whether the records should be fetch as an associative array, numeric array or both. You have no way of fetching an array of objects. e.g.

   ```
   $results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   ```
2. You can also iterate the `mysqli_result` object directly. This will give you results as associative arrays and you can iterate as many times as you'd like.

   ```
   $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM test1");

   foreach ($result as $r) {
       var_dump($r['id']);
   }
   echo '------------------------------------------------------------';
   foreach ($result as $r) {
       var_dump($r['id']);
   }
   ```
3. If the other two options are not flexible enough or you would like to get the results as objects then you need to rely on the other methods i.e. `fetch_object()`, or `fetch_array()`

   ```
   $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM test1");

   $objects = []; // collect objects into an array
   while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
       $objects[] = $obj;
   }
   ```

   The problem here is that you need to get each row separately and you can't iterate again once you reach the end unless you rewind the object's internal pointer. This method can be useful sometimes if you need to apply some transformations when collecting the results.

Of course as a side note I recommend to use PDO instead, which is more powerful less buggy and easier to use.